# Swift - convert value from hashtable to Double

Tags: ios, swift

Newbie to swift, tried a lot of combinations but could not get through. I have a method where I get a list of params via `[AnyHashable : Any]`

In there there are 2 values of latitude and longitude whose values are also strings, I need to extract those values and create a `CLLocationCoordinate` this code :

```
let lat = Double(param["latitude"])
let lng = Double(param["longitude"])
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
```

The let for lat and lng has a compile error with

> No exact matches to call to initializer" how do I go about it?

Comment: `if let lat = param["latitude"] as? Double {}` ? But that would depend on what's `param` really and where it comes from.

Comment: You're not converting from `AnyHashable` to Double. You're fetching values from a dictionary where the key is declared as `AnyHashable`. We need to know what the matching values for those keys contain. Since they are typed as `Any` they could contain any Swift type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it directly

```
guard let lat = param["latitude"] as? Double , 
      let lng = param["longitude"] as? Double else { return } 
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is defined as `[AnyHashable: Any]`.

The keys "latitude" and "longitude" may or may not exist, and the values found at those keys could be any type.

If you know that the values for your "latitude" and "longitude" keys will always be Doubles, or will always be Strings, you could write the conversion either as casts or as casts followed by calls to `Double.init(_:String)`

If your dictionary could contain either String values or Double values, you could write a function that handles either:

```
func returnCoordinate(param: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
    if let lat = param["latitude"] as? Double ,
          let lng = param["longitude"] as? Double {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
    } else if let latString =  param["latitude"] as? String ,
              let lngString = param["longitude"] as? String,
              let lat = Double(latString),
              let lng = Double(lngString)
               {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
    }
    return nil
}
```

That function will return nil if the dictionary keys don't contain either Doubles or Strings. (It would also fail if one key contained a Double value and the other key contained a String, but that seems just silly.)

Comment: Do you know why would CLLocationCoordinate2D and CLLocationCoordinate2DMake initializers crash when used in playground? The only thing that works for me here is CLLocation

Comment: I confess that I gave up on playgrounds a long time ago. They are just too slow and flaky. I generally use MacOS command line tools when I'm tinkering with Foundation classes like this. If it's something ios specific I will build a throw-away iOS app in the simulator.